# How to capture comments nodeType 8 in IE using JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to capture a specific commented line. The following code works ok for every browser except IE of course:

```
<script>
var llf = jQuery('.select').contents().filter(function() {
return this.nodeType === 8 // Comment node
})[2].nodeValue.replace("LLF: ", "").trim();
console.log(llf);
alert(llf);
</script>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<td class="select" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="3">
<!-- NON IDEAL REASON:  1 hour time window -->
<b>$423.59</b><br />
<b>&#163;267.50</b><br />
<!--  Policy Name: Investment Bank -->
<!--LLF: 1253.12 --> //This is the line I want to capture
```

If there is a way to do it for all browsers great but if you can think of a specific solution for IE + conditional comment is also fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't have [`String#trim`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.20), which was only introduced recently in ES5, so it's throwing an exception when you try to use it. But as you're using jQuery, you can use `jQuery.trim` instead:

```
var llf = jQuery.trim(jQuery('.select').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 8; // Comment node
})[2].nodeValue.replace("LLF: ", ""));
console.log(llf);
alert(llf);
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ezuvoh) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ezuvoh) - works for me in IE7 and IE9, so I'm presuming IE8 as well

---

I would recommend breaking that statement down a bit (not least so issues like this are easier to debug), and including the semicolon after the `=== 8`.